# Failed to install bluepy

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have python 3.4 (64) installed, I have also upgraded pip to the latest version.

I have tried to install bluepy package either by using pip or by the command " python setup.py install " from inside the directory of the package.

The installation failed both ways.

[image: Using pip]

[image: Using "python setup.py install" command]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bluepy package only work for linux and i won't install on windows